# TypeError: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"id"' and '"en"' have no overlap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a code like this:

```
interface FirstType {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  lastname: string;
  name: string;
  password: string;
  phone: string;
}

interface SecondType {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  lastname: string;
  name: string;
  password: string;
  phone: string;
  en: LangType;
}

interface LangType {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

type ObjType = FirstType | SecondType;

const data: [FirstType, SecondType] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "sd",
    lastname: "ks",
    name: "sd",
    password: "sfd",
    phone: "sdf",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "sd",
    lastname: "ks",
    name: "sd",
    password: "sfd",
    phone: "sdf",
    en: { name: "a", surname: "b" },
  },
];

const language = "en";

data.map((obj: ObjType) => {
  const newObj: {
    [key: string]: ObjType[keyof ObjType];
  } = { key: obj.id };

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const typedKey = key as keyof ObjType;

    newObj[key] = obj[typedKey];

    if (typedKey !== "id" && typedKey === language && obj[typedKey]) {
      for (let value in obj[typedKey] as LangType) {
        newObj[value] = obj[typedKey][value];
      }
    }
  });

  return newObj;
});
```

but I am getting a typescript error:
"TypeError: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"id"' and '"en"' have no overlap."

How to fix it? I've tried many things but nothing works

Updated. Now a new error: "This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"email" | "lastname" | "name" | "password" | "phone"' and '"en"' have no overlap."

Comment: `SecondType` has property `en` but you use `ru`? how is that possible?

Comment: @Apostolos sorry, there is actually "en", corrected the question

Comment: Qwerty, no, you didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mix up 2 different types `FirstType` and `SecondType` you need to exclude property `id` from `if` statement, since the check is made for the property appearing at `SecondType` only

```
key as keyof ObjType;
```

may be `id` or `en` but the check is made only for second property

```
  if (typedKey !== 'id' && typedKey === language && obj[typedKey]) {
```

Updated answer:

```
interface FirstType {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  lastname: string;
  name: string;
  password: string;
  phone: string;
}

interface SecondType {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  lastname: string;
  name: string;
  password: string;
  phone: string;
  en: LangType;
}

interface LangType {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

type ObjType = FirstType | SecondType

const data: [FirstType, SecondType] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'sd',
    lastname: 'ks',
    name: 'sd',
    password: 'sfd',
    phone: 'sdf'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'sd',
    lastname: 'ks',
    name: 'sd',
    password: 'sfd',
    phone: 'sdf',
    en: { name: 'a', surname: 'b' }
  }
]

const language = 'en'

data.map((obj: ObjType) => {
  const newObj: {
    [key: string]: ObjType[keyof ObjType];
  } = { key: obj.id }

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    type Keys = keyof ObjType
    type LangTypeKeys = keyof LangType
    const typedKey: Keys = key as Keys

    newObj[key] = obj[typedKey]

    if (typedKey.toString() === language && obj[typedKey]) {
      const keys : LangTypeKeys[] = Object.keys(obj[typedKey]) as LangTypeKeys[]
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const lang: LangType = obj[typedKey] as unknown as LangType
        newObj[keys[i]] = (lang as LangType)[keys[i]]
      }
    }
  })

  return newObj
})
```

Comment: thanks, this fixed the error in the condition, but the error appeared in
`for (let value in obj[typedKey])`
: "The right-hand side of a 'for...in' statement must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter, but here has type 'never'"

Comment: it doesn't work but i did `for (let value in obj[typedKey] as LangType)` and it worked, thanks

Comment: weird. it worked at my sample code. anyway dont forget to accept answer if it helped you solve your problem. have a nive day.cheers :)

Comment: but what if I have a lot of data, not just id? For example: `interface SecondType {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  lastname: string;
  name: string;
  password: string;
  phone: string;
  en: LangType;
}`
Is there another way to check?

Comment: it seems that by using `const typedKey: string | LangType = key as keyof ObjType;` it silences all errors. it works at my part of code, at least the code i copied frm your question.

Comment: @Qwerty sorry I had a typo in my snippet `const typedKey: string = key as keyof ObjType;` typedKey will always be string

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. When I try to change the `typedKey`, there are even more errors)

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to check if the object "en" exists. And if it exists, then write its properties to a new object. The result for second object (SecondType) should be: `{
    id: 1,
    email: "sd",
    lastname: "ks",
    password: "sfd",
    phone: "sdf",
    name: "a",
    surname: "b",
  }`

Comment: i think i made it too complicated but it doesnt throw any exceptions. feel free to alter it wherever you want.